# Changing mouse cursor while Ember content is saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I know Ember makes it quite straight forward to display an indicator on route transitions that take a long time.

But what's the easiest way to do the same after a Save button is clicked, and until the save operation completes? I am not finding much on this.

Comment: How are you saving jquery ajax, ember data save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to kingpin2k, I feel this solution pretty nicely handles EmberData Model ajax operations:

```
DS.Model.reopen
  save: ->
    @cursorWait()
    @_super().finally =>
      @cursorDefault()

  createRecord: (hash) ->
    @cursorWait()
    @_super(hash).finally =>
      @cursorDefault()

  destroyRecord: ->
    @cursorWait()
    @_super().finally =>
      @cursorDefault()

  cursorWait: ->
    $('html,body').css('cursor', 'wait')

  cursorDefault: ->
    $('html,body').css('cursor', 'default')
```

And one can still chain a **finally** and/or a **then** while calling the model methods:

```
actions:
  save: ->
    @controller.content.save().then(-> console.log 'then').finally(-> console.log 'another finally')
```

Comment: I like that, I'm not sure if it's necessary on createRecord since that's done entirely client side, but it's very clean looking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming based off the tag you are using ember data

```
$('html,body').css('cursor','crosshair');
record.save().finally(function(){
  // revert mouse
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html#method_finally

Obviously this is limited, and crosshair, but it shows the general idea, and typing in a phone sucks, I apologize.