# How do I display a busy cursor during a route transition in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

What is the best technique to generically change to a busy cursor during transition to a new route in Ember.js (1.13.10)? With data retrieval, this may take a couple of seconds.

The answer here indicates a method to do this with saving data:

[Changing mouse cursor while Ember content is saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332998/changing-mouse-cursor-while-ember-content-is-saving)

...and indicates this is very straight forward with route transitions, but I can't seem to find an example or anything in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[We can use `loading` hook of `Route`.](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_loading)

app/routes/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    loading(transition, route) {
      $('body').css({ cursor : 'wait' });

      this.router.one('didTransition', () => {
        $('body').css({ cursor: 'default' });
      });

      return true; // Bubble the loading event
    }
  }
});
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/3e74cff240e037c5cdf9) (output is sandboxed so make sure your mouse is over body in output window)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/3e74cff240e037c5cdf9)

I've used `$('body')` as element to style `cursor`. You can probably use more *global* approach.